# Delete local Git branches if their remote-tracking references don't exist anymore

Tags: git, github, version-control, branch, git-branch

I have a local and a remote Git repository.

- In my local repository I create and switch to a new branch: `git checkout -b feature/niceNewFeature`
- I do my coding, `git add .`, `git commit` and `git push` my `feature/niceNewFeature` branch to the remote repository (e.g. GitHub).
- After this I create a GitHub Pull Request to merge `feature/niceNewFeature` branch into `master` - after the code is reviewed, I will do so.
- Since `feature/niceNewFeature` is now merged to `master`, I will delete it on GitHub.
- However, in my local repository, feature/niceNewFeature branch is still listed if I execute `git branch` command.

How do I remove `feature/niceNewFeature` branch from my local repository, since it is already merged to `master` and deleted from the remote repository?

Comment: Use this command with the `--purge` flag `git fetch --all --purge` it will remove all branches and tags etc

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### Short answer:

`git fetch --prune`

`git branch -lvv | cut -c3- | awk '/: gone]/ {print $1}' | xargs git branch -d`

### Detailed answer:

*Firstly*, remove any remote-tracking references that no longer exist on the remote:

`git fetch --prune` (or `git fetch -p`)

If you do this, and then you run `git branch -vv` (verbose), you will see that although `feature/niceNewFeature` branch is still listed, the upstream branch is now "gone":

```
feature/niceNewFeature  832f7a7 [origin/feature/niceNewFeature: gone] Some commit message.
```

*Secondly*, let's remove the local branches, with the following command:

`git branch -lvv | cut -c3- | awk '/: gone]/ {print $1}' | xargs git branch -d`

What it does, is basically the following:

1. Lists all local (`-l`) branches in verbose mode (`vv`) (that's almost like our previous output)
2. It `cut`s the first and second characters from the beginning of every line (which are spaces)
3. With `awk` it filters the "gone" ones (`/: gone]/`), and gets their first column (`{print $1}`). Remember, the "gone" means that the remote-tracking reference doesn't exist anymore.
4. The output (which is the name of the branch to be deleted, `feature/niceNewFeature` in our case) is piped to `git branch -d` (delete) with `xargs` command, so it will delete the branch. Note that the branch must be fully merged in its upstream branch, because only `-d` option is used, not `-D` (which is `--delete --force`).

Comment: This answer is, in my opinion, better than the accepted answer on the duplicate (but does appear as additional answers there as well).

Comment: fwiw, (on my machine) this can be simplified to `git branch -vv | awk '/: gone]/ {print $1}' | xargs git branch -d` (the `-l` flag and `cut` command are unnecessary)

Comment: Bash alias taking in account single quotes: `alias youralias='git branch -lvv | cut -c3- | awk '"'"'/: gone]/ {print $1}'"'"' | xargs git branch -d'`